# How to create an equals method that compares two object arrays of a class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, boolean

I am trying to create a equals method that compares two objects. The thing is, I'm a bit a of new to this stuff so I'll try to explain my goal as easy as possible.

```
public class A {
...
}

public class B {
private A[] arr = new A[10];

public boolean equals(A[] temp) {
//compare
}
}
```

Assume the code above is a summary of what I have. Now, assume I had: `arr.equals(Obj)`
Obj being another A[] object. Now in my equals statement, I want to reference the original `arr` array, how do I go about doing that?

For example, let's say I wanted to compare arr's length to temp's length (aka Obj's length), how would I do that? I know it would be something like (temp.length == arr.length) but how do I access arr when I pass it through by doing `arr.equals(obj)`?

EDIT: Just to clarify, assume the objects aren't simple arrays. So for instance, class A could have a Name, a Type (Both Strings) and possibly a Quantity (an int), so I wouldn't be able to simply compare them like they're two normal arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: [`Arrays#equals(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `this`, which always represents the object you are applying the method to (immediately before the dot).  For example:

```
    public boolean equals(A[] temp) {
        return this.length == temp.length ;
    }
```

Now, in the particular case of your code, you are not defining method `equals` as part of class `A`, but of a class `B` whose instances contain `arr`.  Then, the solution would be:

```
    public boolean equals(A[] temp) {
        return this.arr.length == temp.length ;
    }
```

Comment: This was my original idea, I had if (this.length == temp.length), but Eclipse is telling me "length cannot be resolved or is not a field." for this.length. Is that normal? I can still compile.

Comment: this.length is not defined in B, in B you have defined arr, and arr has a length if you read again Mario Rossi's answer you will see that this.length is a generic way to represent the issue and then he shows a particular case for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Arrays.equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2) which tests if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one another

Answer (score 0):

Write a equals mwthod in your `class A`

```
public class A {
...
//Override equals method.

}
```

Now if you want to compare 2 arrays of `class A` you can simply use `java.utils.Arrays.equals(A a1[], A a2[]);`

You have to override equals method in `class A` coz java.utils.Arrays.equals internally uses class A's equals.

Here is an [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_deepequals.htm), go through it.